# extract a certain quote after a keyword has been detected in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a multi-term definer to quicken the process of searching for the definitions individually.
After python loads a webpage, it saves the page as a temporary text file.

Sample of saved page: `..."A","Answer":"","Abstract":"Harriet Tubman was an American abolitionist.","ImageIs...` 
In this sample, I'm after the string that contains the definition, in this case Harriet Tubman. The string `"Abstract":` is the portion always before the definition of the term.

What I need is a way to scan the text file for `"Abstract":`. Once that has been detected, look for an opening `"`. Then, copy and save all text to another text file until reaching the end `"`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *just* wanted to find the string following `"Abstract:"` you could take a substring.

```
page = '..."A","Answer":"","Abstract":"Harriet Tubman was an American abolitionist.","ImageIs...'
i = page.index("Abstract") + 11 
defn = page[i: page.index("\"", i)]
```

If you wanted to extract multiple parts of the page you should try the following.

```
dict_str = '"Answer":"","Abstract":"Harriet Tubman was an American abolitionist."'
definitions = {}
for kv in dict_str.split(","):
    parts = kv.replace("\"", "").split(":")
    if len(parts) != 2:
        continue
    definitions[parts[0]] = parts[1]

definitions['Abstract'] # 'Harriet Tubman was an American abolitionist.'
definitions["Answer"] # ''
```

Comment: Is this just work only for example above? Do we need to use regex for more global answer?

Comment: On second thought, the author says they just need a way to scan for `Abstract` so regex and dictionary might be too much

Comment: alz2 presented a viable answer. Nearly perfect. Only thing is, when I have a definition with multiple commas in between, the extracted definition is cut off.

Comment: Oops; you're right! In that case if OP wanted to lookup multiple keys then regex's should be the way to go I think